# Check For Empty Array From JSON

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

I am trying to get an array of strings from JSON and I'm trying to figure out how to deal with it if the returned array is empty. In some cases, the returned value is [] and for other cases, the array contains string values. It is crashing because of unexpectedly finding a nil value.

For clarification, the gyms array is passed from another class and everything here works without the code for the images.

Here is my relevant code:

```
var gyms = [AnyObject]()
var imageArrays = [[String]?]()
```

In viewDidLoad()

```
getGymImages()
```

Methods to get JSON data:

```
func getGymImages() {
        var index = 0

        for dictionary in gyms {
            let id = dictionary["id"] as! String

            let urlString = String("https://gyminyapp.azurewebsites.net/api/GymImage/\(id)")
            let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
            let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)

            do {
                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
                for imageArray in json as! [AnyObject] {
                    imageArrays.append((imageArray as? [String])!)
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error")
            }

            index += 1
        }

        addImagesToGyms()
    }

    func addImagesToGyms() {
        var index = 0;

        for array in imageArrays {
            var dictionary = gyms[index] as! [String:AnyObject]
            dictionary["images"] = array
            gyms[index] = dictionary

            index += 1
        }
    }
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath()

```
let gymImages = dictionary["images"] as! [String]
        if gymImages.count > 0 {
            let firstImageURL = gymImages[0] as String
            cell.cellImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: firstImageURL))
        }
```

**EDIT: I was asked to show more of the file, so here it is.**

```
import UIKit

class GymListTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var gyms = [AnyObject]()
    var gymName: String?
    var gymAddress: String?
    var gymPhoneNumber: String?
    var gymWebsite: String?
    var gymID: String?
    var gymLatitude: String?
    var gymLongitude: String?
    var maxDistance: Double?
    var myLocation: CLLocation?
    var milesArray = [Double]()
    var imageArrays = [[String]?]()

    var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.title = "Gyms"

        tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "GymListTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "gymCell")

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "waypoint_map"), style: .Done, target: self, action: #selector(showMapView))
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = BarItems.greenTintColor

        segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: ["A-Z", "Z-A", "Rating", "Distance"])
        segmentedControl?.sizeToFit()
        segmentedControl?.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
        segmentedControl!.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name:"Helvetica-Light", size: 15)!],
                                       forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        segmentedControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(changeSelectedSegmentIndex), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
        self.navigationItem.titleView = segmentedControl

        sortAlphabetically()

        let backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "gray_background")
        let backgroundImageView = UIImageView(image: backgroundImage)
        tableView.backgroundView = backgroundImageView

        addDistancesToGyms()
        getGymImages()

        // geocodeAddresses()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func addDistancesToGyms() {
        var index = 0

        for distance in milesArray {
            var dictionary = gyms[index] as! [String:AnyObject]
            dictionary["distance"] = distance

            gyms[index] = dictionary

            index += 1
        }
    }

    func getGymImages() {
        var index = 0

        for dictionary in gyms {
            let id = dictionary["id"] as! String

            let urlString = String("https://gyminyapp.azurewebsites.net/api/GymImage/\(id)")
            let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
            let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)

            do {
                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
                for imageArray in json as! [AnyObject] {
                    imageArrays.append((imageArray as? [String])!)
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error")
            }

            index += 1
        }

        addImagesToGyms()
    }

    func addImagesToGyms() {
        var index = 0;

        for array in imageArrays {
            var dictionary = gyms[index] as! [String:AnyObject]
            dictionary["images"] = array
            gyms[index] = dictionary

            index += 1
        }
    }

    func changeSelectedSegmentIndex() {
        let segmentTouched = segmentedControl?.selectedSegmentIndex

        if segmentTouched == 0 {
            sortAlphabetically()
        } else if segmentTouched == 1 {
            sortReverseAlphabetically()
        } else if segmentTouched == 2 {
            sortByRatingAscending()
        } else {
            sortByDistanceAscending()
        }
    }

    func sortAlphabetically() {
        gyms.sortInPlace{
            (($0 as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)["name"] as? String) < (($1 as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)["name"] as? String)
        }

        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func sortReverseAlphabetically() {
        gyms.sortInPlace{
            (($0 as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)["name"] as? String) > (($1 as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)["name"] as? String)
        }

        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func sortByRatingAscending() {
        // TODO: Sort by rating
    }

    func sortByDistanceAscending() {
        gyms.sortInPlace{
            (($0 as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)["distance"] as? Double) < (($1 as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)["distance"] as? Double)
        }

        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func showMapView() {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("displayMapSegue", sender: self.navigationController)
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return gyms.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 131
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("gymCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GymListTableViewCell

        let dictionary = gyms[indexPath.row]
        let addressDictionary = dictionary["address"]
        let street = addressDictionary!!["streetAddress"] as! String
        let city = addressDictionary!!["city"] as! String
        let state = addressDictionary!!["state"] as! String

        let zipInt = addressDictionary!!["zipCode"] as! Int
        let zipCode = String(zipInt)

        let addressString = String("\(street) " + "\(city), " + "\(state) " + "\(zipCode)")

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        cell.gymNameLabel.text = dictionary["name"] as? String
        cell.gymAddressLabel.text = addressString

        let miles = dictionary["distance"] as! Double
        let milesString = String(format: "%.1f miles", miles)
        let milesLabelString = milesString
        cell.milesLabel.text = milesLabelString

        let gymImages = dictionary["images"] as! [String]
        if gymImages.count > 0 {
            let firstImageURL = gymImages[0] as String
            cell.cellImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: firstImageURL))
        }

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let dictionary = gyms[indexPath.row]

        if dictionary["name"] as? String != nil {
            self.gymName = dictionary["name"] as? String
        }

        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! GymListTableViewCell
        self.gymAddress = cell.gymAddressLabel.text

        if dictionary["phone"] as? String != nil {
            self.gymPhoneNumber = dictionary["phone"] as? String
        }

        if dictionary["website"] as? String != nil {
            self.gymWebsite = dictionary["website"] as? String
        }

        if dictionary["id"] as? String != nil {
            self.gymID = dictionary["id"] as? String
        }

        if dictionary["latitude"] as? String != nil {
            self.gymLatitude = dictionary["latitude"] as? String
        }

        if dictionary["longitude"] as? String != nil {
            self.gymLongitude = dictionary["longitude"] as? String
        }

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("detailFromListSegue", sender: self.navigationController)
    }

    // MARK: - Navigation

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "detailFromListSegue" {
            let gymDetailVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailTableViewController
            if self.gymName != nil {
                gymDetailVC.gymName = self.gymName
            } else {
                gymDetailVC.gymName = nil
            }

            if self.gymAddress != nil {
                gymDetailVC.gymAddress = self.gymAddress
            } else {
                gymDetailVC.gymAddress = nil
            }

            if self.gymPhoneNumber != nil {
                gymDetailVC.gymPhoneNumber = self.gymPhoneNumber
            } else {
                gymDetailVC.gymPhoneNumber = nil
            }

            if self.gymWebsite != nil {
                gymDetailVC.gymWebsite = self.gymWebsite
            } else {
                gymDetailVC.gymWebsite = nil
            }

            if self.gymID != nil {
                gymDetailVC.gymID = self.gymID!
            } else {
                // gymDetailVC.gymID = nil
            }

            if self.gymLatitude != nil {
                gymDetailVC.gymLatitude = self.gymLatitude!
            }

            if self.gymLongitude != nil {
                gymDetailVC.gymLongitude = self.gymLongitude!
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At what point are you crashing from the unexpected nil? In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: It crashes in getGymImages(), right after assigning the value to id.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're appending anything to `gyms` at any point. Surely `for dictionary in gyms` will never do anything?

Comment: The gyms array is passed from another class. It all works without the code for the images.

Comment: Sorry, just to confirm - its return unexpected nil because of this line : `let id = dictionary["id"] as! String` If so then the dictionary doesn't contain a record with the key "id"

Comment: No, the crash is after that line. I placed a print statement there to confirm it was getting the id.

Comment: I'm fairly certain this has to do with the fact that in some cases the array returned from JSON is empty

Comment: That's definitely possible. Also if data is nil from `let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)` it will also crash due to the unwrapping in the `NSJSONSerialization` part.

Comment: Unrelated, but instead of creating index and adding to it each time inside of your `for value in array` loops you can use `for (index, value) in array.enumerate()` to keep track of the index and value for that item in the array

Answer (score 0):

`numberOfRowsInSection` should be returning `gymImages.count` if it isn't already.

Then as a safeguard you can always do

```
if indexPath.row < gymImages.count {

}
```

before accessing the content in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: It is returning gyms.count

Comment: Can we see more of the file?